# How to know if Delete button is tapped on iOS 6 UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any way, we can get to know that delete button on the UITableViewCell is tapped in iOS 6. In iOS 7, showingDeleteConfirmation property is set to NO but in iOS 6 it remain YES.

I want to differentiate when the red - button is tapped and when Delete button is tapped. This is working fine in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6.

Comment: Doesn't the '-' red button only appear when your in editing mode? Then you can just check via the `cell.editing` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you still need this, but if I understand correctly you can subclass the `UITableViewCell` and use `-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state` to check `UITableViewCellStateMask` for `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`

```
-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state 
{
     if ( (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask )
    {
      // showing delete confirmation 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the delegate callback on your view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //Tap delete here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1.First add `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in your header file..

2.Add this code to check delete confirmation

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
          NSLog(@"Delete Success");
    }

    else
    {
          NSLog(@"Delete Canceled");
    }
}
```